# ASP.NET/Javascript hyperlink popup menu upon left click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hyperlink, popupmenu

I need to display a mobile-phone compatible popup menu when user left-clicks a HyperLink control. A menu will contain various options for this link, so its handler had to be aware of the clicked link data (actually, each link corresponds to a nickname).

What do I need to make that work?:)

Comment: Oh, that's great for your users. And what is that you want to ask about?

Comment: you'll need asp.net and javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links with pop menou.

http://www.php-development.ru/javascripts/dropdown.php

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/index.html

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

I think that there are too many more to find on google.